"error": "invalid_client" django-oauth-toolkit with grant_type = 'authentication_code'
So, i'm following this tutorial to apply oauth2 in my django project
I handled to get an client_id, secret, code_verifier and code as it is described in the tutorial but then the tutorial asks the following:

Now that you have the user authorization is time to get an access token:


curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/" -d "client_id=${ID}" -d "client_secret=${SECRET}" -d "code=${CODE}" -d "code_verifier=${CODE_VERIFIER}" -d "redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/noexist/callback" -d "grant_type=authorization_code"

I tried everything, checked the credentials 100 of times but the terminal output is always: {"error": "invalid_client"}
I can't see what is wrong

One common cause for this error is not providing the client secret when it’s required.  Ensure that your client secret, id, code etc. you supplied are correct. Did you forget to migrate your project after you must have installed the package, and done the necessary settings.py configuration for the project to work? How about the urls.py registration of the project, did you forget to do that? Please check well?

I'm trying to use all-auth instead of django oauth toolkit, but, yeah, everything registered correctly. I even saved my credentials in a .txt to check if everything was ok.

Brilliant idea. So, no issue again, right?

no. It's not working...

Have you tried this with the hard-coded values instead of using variables? One issue could be that these values have not been correctly set. Getting the code means that the client is valid and you could finish the first part of the flow. Other things that could go wrong: the code_verifier should be the original value (not the hashed one) and the redirect_uri needs to be correct.
